# Show only unique data for a column - jQuery data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, unique, datatables

I am using [Data Tables](https://datatables.net/) and want to show only unique data for a column `day`.

This is my table:

```
#   Day         Count
---------------------
1   Friday      2
2   Friday      2
3   Saturday    4
.   .       .
.   .       .
```

JS:

```
var myTable = $('.table').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "oLanguage": {
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "&larr;", // This is the link to the previous page
                "sNext": "&rarr;", // This is the link to the next page
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I filter the data to show only unique days data in table ?

I know there is [unique()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/unique()) function there but thats for only selecting unique column data from the table, instead I need the (by rebuilding may be) table show the column with unique data.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you fetching the data and displaying on the table?

Comment: From an api, but its not the requirement to send unique from the api. @sgt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by creating a [custom row filter](http://datatables.net/development/filtering#row_filters) :

```js
var day,
    days = [];

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        //return true if iDataIndex already is processed
        if (days[iDataIndex]) return true;
        //process day, return true and insert into days if not already known
        day = aData[1];        
        if (days.indexOf(day)<0) {
           days[iDataIndex]=day;
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }     
    }     
);
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4abqjxcu/**